# What virtualization software are you running on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, virtualization

I have Windows 7, and I need to setup a dev environment consisting of multiple server OSes:
I need a PerformancePoint 2007 server, a MOSS server, and a SQL Server, and a domain controller (might be my SQL Server, not sure yet).  This is just to replicate a bug in production.

Anyway, what should I be using for my virtualization needs?  I have Windows Virtual PC, but can it have 64-bit guests?  I need a free solution, even if it's a free trial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think VPC supports 64-bit guests yet, but [**VirtualBox**](http://www.virtualbox.org/) is free and supports 64-bit guests, provided you have capable hardware.

You may like their comparison page, [**VirtualBox vs Others**](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/VBox_vs_Others).

Comment: didn't see on the page - does VirtualBox support VHD images?

Comment: @Nathan yep! vbox supports VHD images. They added it in 2.1.0 ( http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog-2.1 )

Answer (score 2):

The newest version of [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) now allows you to create VMs, not just run ones already created.

Answer (score 1):

**[VMLite](http://www.vmlite.com/)** is **free** and

- supports 3D/2D acceleration
- supports multiple virtual CPUs
- supports VM hibernation
- supports 32- and **64- bit** host and **guest operating systems**
- supports running 64-bit guest operating systems on 32-bit host when VT-x or AMD-V is enabled
- supports VMware (VMDK), Microsoft (**VHD**), Sun (VDI) and Parallel (HDD) virtual disk formats
- supports live snapshots for easy and fast recovery